# Converting a String or base10 to a base 2 in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unit-conversion

I am looking for a way to take a value from a text box and convert it into a base 2 number with 8 digits.
So if they type in a text box 2 it would respond 00000010. or if they typed 255 11111111. etc... 
is there any way to do this.

```
Dim prVal As Integer

prVal = PrefixTxt.Text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Convert.ToString` method and specify the base as 2.  This will convert an `Integer` value into a `String` in the specified base

```
Dim result = Convert.ToString(Integer.Parse(prVal), 2)
```

As @Dan pointed out if you want to force this to be width 8 use the `PadLeft` method

```
result = result.PadLeft(8, "0"c)
```

Comment: @Dan good call, updated to account for that

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToString(Integer.Parse(prVal), 2).PadLeft(8, '0')
```

Comment: A `char` in VB is expressed with `"0"c` and not `'0'`.

Comment: oh thanks :) a day-to-day C# guru ...

Comment: Yeah it's a really strange syntax if you're coming from a C based language